# Website display problem - across all browsers

Tags: browser

whenever I go to [getpersonas.com](http://getpersonas.com) or [youtube](http://www.youtube.com) the page loads like this:

[image: Screenshot Example]

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm experiencing this too. My findings: it is not OS dependent (also happens with Windows 7), it is not browser dependent (Opera, Chrome/Chromium, Firefox), it doesn't matter if I connect via my router or the modem (PPPoE), I tried different DNS w/o luck. One page that fails quite often for me is https://bugzilla.gnome.org - all in all: this doesn't look like an Ubuntu problem. :-|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright I finally got it working.  The problem was my ISP's DNS doesn't play nice with Ubuntu.  So I changed my DNS to [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) and that fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this is because your browser is not loading the stylesheet, which is hosted on [another domain](http://getpersonas-cdn.mozilla.net/static/min/?g=css&r=74591). Possible reasons could be due to the stylesheet domain being blocked or because your browser is failing to get DNS resolution for it.

Try reaching getpersonas.com through a web proxy like:

http://www.zendproxy.com

If the site displays properly via proxy, then try to disable ipv6. To do that in Firefox:

1. Type **about:config** in the address bar, press Enter.
2. Find **network.dns.disableIPv6** in the list.
3. Right-click -> Toggle.
4. Restart Firefox and try again.

You can also disable ipv6 on the system level, so other browsers don't get affected by ipv6 issues. To do that, open the file  /etc/default/grub with an editor:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Then change the following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”
```

With the following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”ipv6.disable=1 quiet splash”
```

Then update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

You can also try a different DNS server like [OpenDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDNS) or [Google Public DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Public_DNS).

Comment: Why do you think this is the reason?

Comment: Because that is a problem that happens on Mozilla sites. For instance, is common for users with ipv6 enable to not being able to install extensions and I have already seen css issues as well.

Comment: @JanC  BTW, the personas site pulls the css from a different domain http://getpersonas-cdn.mozilla.net/static/min/?g=css&r=74591, which is probably the cause of the ipv6 interference.

Comment: That domain doesn't have AAAA records in DNS, so that shouldn't give problems...

Comment: @lovinglinux turning off ipv6 in about:config didn't helped me, I also have a windows on the same computer and it works there (in case this could help), using latest ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Were you able to see the site properly when loading it via proxy? Have you tried to cleanup the cache after disabling ipv6? Can you reach the css file directly via http://getpersonas-cdn.mozilla.net/static/min/?g=css&r=74591 ?

Comment: @lovinglinux via proxy I see it; clearing the cache even after disable ipv6 doesn't help; in mozilla I do viewsource click on css files links and it gives me "server not found", just like bing.com

Comment: @Omu Try to temporarily disable Firefox DNS cache using the following extension https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5914/

Comment: @lovinglux I don't think is firefox's fault, I'll try some older version of ubuntu, the 10.10 looks buggy, with a full battery after I unplug my power cable it tells that the battery is empty

Comment: @lovinglinux version 10.04 didn't helped for the browser problem

Comment: @Omu Try a different DNS server. I have included options at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you aren't loading the stylesheet. Clear your cache or hit <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set up a new Firefox profile for testing reasons. First, make sure all instances of Firefox are closed! It might take some time for the process to end even though Firefox is not visible any more.
If the commands below do not work make sure Firefox is closed by typing the following in a shell.

```
killall firefox-bin
```

Then run the Firefox Profile Manager. You can do that by entering the following command from a shell or by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and entering it there:

```
firefox -profilemanager
```

You can setup a new profile there and try if it works with that fresh one. Be aware that the newly created profile will be set as new default. Do switch back to your original profile you have to start the profile manager again and select to start the appropriate profile.

See [MozillaZine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_manager) for more information on the profile manager.

If just read lovinglinux's answer and just wanted to let you know that - in case you tried to solve the issue with a new profile - you should get the same problem again, as setting up a new profile also uses the default `about:config` settings which are to use ipv6 by default (`network.dns.disableIPv6=False`). If the new profile solved your problems we have to search somewhere else for the problem. See [MozillaZine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.dns.disableIPv6) for details on the option.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a problem with the CSS file(s). Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and/or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to force a reload of not only the page but the associated files.

If that doesn't work you could try clearing your cache (an option in [Clear Recent History](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Clear+Recent+History)).

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use the latest [Opera 10 browser](http://www.opera.com/) with Turbo Mode turned on.