# Some websites display incorrectly (multiple browsers)

Tags: firefox, chromium

I have noticed recently that a few websites display incorrectly: www.dropbox.com and www.mediafire.com. They appear to only be loading a very minimal version of there websites (see attachments). All other websites appear to load and function as expected.

This issue happens with both Firefox and Chromium. I also have the same issue with both Internet Explorer and Firefox when run in in Virtual Box with Windows Xp as guest.

These websites display as expected on my other pc which has windows as the OS.

This leads me to believe it is more than an Internet browser issue, but I have tried the standard troubleshooting steps anyways: clearing cache, cookies, ect...

I thought it could be an user agent issue, but it seems fine to me.

Any ideas?

---

OS Version: Ubuntu 13.10.2 64 bit

User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0

Firefox 25.0.1
Chromium 30.0.1599.114

No Proxy, No Software Firewall installed, Have disabled all browser add-ons

---

http://dropbox.com on Firefox:

[image]

---

http://mediafire.com on Chromium:

[image]

Comment: This happens to me when I don't have much bandwidth. Is it repeatable if you refresh? Are you running any internet intensive processes? Are you getting DNS errors?

Comment: Yes it has been happening for at least 3 days and every time I load the pages (I don't normally go to theses sites so don't know how long). No intensive bandwidth processes and all other sites load quickly and correctly. No DNS errors.

Comment: I found similar issue on:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/10342/website-display-problem-across-all-browsers?rq=1

The solution that worked for me was to change my DNS to OpenDNS per post:

"Alright I finally got it working. The problem was my ISP's DNS doesn't play nice with Ubuntu. So I changed my DNS to OpenDNS and that fixed it."